# Move into a subfolder all 1-level folders inside a parent directory if a foldersize is set

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory (`anime`) that have many folders with different folder sizes.
I want to move all that folders inside a subfolder called "over40gb" if these folders have a size over 40gb

I test a script but this works only if I want to move one folder (called 'tomove') into another one folder (called 'over40gb')

```
if [ $(du -m -s tomove/ | cut -f1) -gt 40000 ] ; then 
  mv tomove/ $HOME/over40gb/
fi
```

Is possible to extend this script for all folders (just 1-level folders) inside `anime` directory into `over40gb` subfolder ?

I start from this situation

```
anime
  |
  + tomove1 (30 gb)
  + tomove2 (45 gb)
  + tomove3 (40 gb)
```

And I want to move in this way

```
anime
  |
  + tomove1 (30 gb)
  |
  + over40gb
       |
       + tomove2 (45 gb)
       + tomove3 (40 gb)
```

Comment: `for tomove in anime/*/; do ... "$tomove" ...; done`

Comment: @jhnc why you write `for tomove in anime/*/` ? inside anime directory I have many folders while `tomove` folder is just a folder name inside anime. For example I can have also `tomove2` folder to move, not only `tomove1`

Comment: I have updated question showing what I would like to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want level one folders then it's as simple as this

```
z=$HOME/theanime/
mkdir -p $HOME/over40gb/
for x in $(ls -1 --color=never -d ${z}*/); do
  y=$(du --max-depth=0 --block-size=1M $x | awk '{print $1}')
  if [ $y -ge 40000 ]; then
    mv ${x} $HOME/ofer40gb/
  fi
done
```

if you need anything else than level one folders i'm going to need to edit this answer.

the "over40gb" folder is in the same directory as the tomove directory's but you could just change that

Comment: mm.. your solution is good but don't move *folders* ≥ 4  from $HOME into *one* subfolder 'over40gb' inside $HOME but it rename folders ≥ 4 in different over40gb names. Look [HERE](https://s8.gifyu.com/images/20220606_160054.gif). I don't want to loose original folder names so is also useful your solution, you could insert only a prefix like #40gb ? before folder names ?

Comment: ok so i solved the issue, it was actuary pretty dumb, but it's fixed now. essentially it was declaring z=$HOME/ in the beginning but for the du part it accidentally redeclared z but as a different value instead of declaring a new value as y. Sorry my bad

Comment: sorry for any folder name loses. It's crazy just how much of a difference a singe mistake can make.

Comment: ops i made a mistake again

Comment: Something is missing because I change `mv ${x} ${z}test/` in `mv ${x} ${z}over40gb/` in this way folders ≥ 4 are moved correctly but it tell me `mv: cannot move '/home/Peter/over40gb/' to a subdirectory of itself, '/home/Peter/over40gb/over40gb'`

Comment: i would suggest running `mkdir $HOME/theanime/ && mv tomove* $HOME/theanime/`

Comment: alright so the problem now is that it detects ofer40gb but it treats it like any of the other folders so it tries to move it's self into it's self. The solution so to put all of the **tomove** folders not a new directory `$HOME/theanime/` and change `${x}over40gb` to `$HOME/over40gb/` and change `z=$HOME/` to `z=$HOME/theanime/` and change `mv ${x} ${z}ofer40gb/` to `mv ${x} $HOME/ofer40gb/`

Comment: i am determined to get this right

Comment: Ok, just another thing: I use cygwin and I need to do this on this path `Z:\ANIME E CARTONI\# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD\# 22`, I try to rewrite it like `z='/cygdrive/Z/ANIME E CARTONI/# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD/# 22/theanime/'` but after running it tell me *ls: cannot access '22/theanime/*/': No such file or directory* ? How should I rewrite this path ? over40gb folder is created correctly but folders are not moved

Comment: not obvious to me what this gains over simply `for x in ${z}*/; do` (which I note is precisely what I suggested doing in my comment on the question...)

Comment: As the question specifies bash, calling awk is unnecessary: `y=($(du --max-depth=0 --block-size=1M $x))` will give the same result (note extra parentheses that make y an array, from which `$y` becomes the zeroth element

Comment: to avoid trying to copy `over40gb` into itself if it is inside `theanime`, just test `$x` as first step in loop. eg. `[ "$x" = "$HOME/over40gb/" ] && continue`

Comment: when doing files and folders with spaces in between bash won't recognize it correctly, you need to change `z='/cygdrive/Z/ANIME E CARTONI/# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD/# 22/theanime/' `  to `z="/cygdrive/Z/ANIME\ E\ CARTONI/#\ DA\ SISTEMARE\ ED\ ESTRARRE\ _\ DVD/#\ 22/theanime/"`

Comment: Can you add your code with this new path, please ? I try to write in [THIS](https://pastebin.com/raw/0MH5AhCy) way but it return me every time some errors or create strange folders your

Comment: could you run the command `echo $PWD` in you're linux home directory and show me send me the exact results. It is quite important for me to know exactly how terminal emulator handles directories

Comment: sure, you can see in this picture that script try to create anomaly folders taken names from path name https://i.imgur.com/Dhloynq.png

Comment: i don't think you need `/cygdrive/Z/ANIME\ E\ CARTONI/#\ DA\ SISTEMARE\ ED\ ESTRARRE\ _\ DVD/#\ 22/` as echo $PWD clearly shows that it's properly virtualized so i see no problem in running the answer i gave up top as is without modifying anything

Comment: `/cygdrive/Z/ANIME\ E\ CARTONI/#\ DA\ SISTEMARE\ ED\ ESTRARRE\ _\ DVD/#\ 22/` is most likely just some way for windows to communicate with the bash shell emulator

Comment: yes, your solution is good for HOME folder but I need to create over40gb into `Z:\ANIME E CARTONI\# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD\# 22` path and move folders ≥ 40 gb

Comment: I'm terribly sorry to say this but my knowledge dose not extend this far when it come to linux emulators communicating with a windows host machine. Someone else is going to have to take over here.